# filter json based on key value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below JSON data. I want to filter based on Key value pairs that is based on Department and Employee

```
 var data = {
    "Item": [
        {
            "Fields": [
              {
                  "Key": "Title",
                  "Value": ""
              },
              {
                  "Key":"Name",
                  "Value":"Phani"
              },
              {  
                  "Key":"Designation",
                  "Value":"Software Eng"
              },
              {  
                  "Key":"Salary",
                  "Value":""
              },
              {  
                  **"Key":"Section",**
                  "Value":"Employee"
              }], "ItemName": "Test"
        },

         {
             "Fields": [
               {
                   "Key": "Title",
                   "Value": ""
               },
               {
                   "Key": "Name",
                   "Value": "Raju"
               },
               {
                   "Key": "Designation",
                   "Value": "Software Eng"
               },
               {
                   "Key": "Salary",
                   "Value": ""
               },
               {
                   "Key": "Section",
                   "Value": "Employee"
               }], "ItemName": "Test"
         },
         {
             "Fields": [
               {
                   "Key": "Title",
                   "Value": ""
               },
               {
                   "Key": "DepName",
                   "Value": "Finance"
               },
               {
                   "Key": "DepType",
                   "Value": "Money"
               },
               {
                   "Key": "Salary",
                   "Value": ""
               },
               {
                   "Key": "Section",
                   "Value": "Department"
               }], "ItemName": "Test"
         },
         {
             "Fields": [
               {
                   "Key": "Title",
                   "Value": ""
               },
               {
                   "Key": "DepName",
                   "Value": "IT"
               },
               {
                   "Key": "DepType",
                   "Value": "Tech"
               },
               {
                   "Key": "Salary",
                   "Value": ""
               },
               {
                   "Key": "Section",
                   "Value": "Department"
               }], "ItemName": "Test"
         }



    ]


};
```

In the above json data if you observe in Fields array i have key value pairs
There is a key with name Section and its value.

I want to filter the data based on Section, like i want to list all the employees and all the departments. Confused about iterating. could you please help with this.

I want two objects ans output
var emps =[]
var deps=[]

so that i can iterate and access like emp["Designation"] emp["Name"]
dep["DepName"] etc

Comment: So you want to flatten this and get a list of key-value pairs?

Comment: Can you please post your expected output?

Comment: Yes i want to get key value pairs based on section, all the employees should go into one array and all the Departments should go into another array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be:

```
var result = {};
data.Item.forEach(function(item){
var fields = item.Fields;
var res = {};
for(var i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
{
  res[fields[i].Key] = fields[i].Value;
}
if(!result.hasOwnProperty(res.Section)){
 result[res.Section] = [];
}
 result[res.Section].push(res);
})
console.log(result);
```

o/p:

```
{ Employee: 
   [ { Title: '',
       Name: 'Phani',
       Designation: 'Software Eng',
       Salary: '',
       Section: 'Employee' },
     { Title: '',
       Name: 'Raju',
       Designation: 'Software Eng',
       Salary: '',
       Section: 'Employee' } ],
  Department: 
   [ { Title: '',
       DepName: 'Finance',
       DepType: 'Money',
       Salary: '',
       Section: 'Department' },
     { Title: '',
       DepName: 'IT',
       DepType: 'Tech',
       Salary: '',
       Section: 'Department' } ] }
```

You can access each employee as `result.Employee[i].Title` and department as `result.Department[0].Title`.

Comment: Your code works fine, but what if there are multiple sections like Hardware, HouseKeeping there will be multiple if conditions right? is there anyway we can refactor this

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea:

```
var firstFields = data.Item[0].Fields.map(function(field){
    return { key: field.Key, value: field.Value };
});

console.log(firstFields);
```

`map()` the data and create the structure that you prefer.

I will update with an example on how to differentiate between employees and departments.

http://jsfiddle.net/kwpy35hg/

Update:

```
// filter out departments
var departments = data.Item.filter(function(item){
    var section = item.Fields[item.Fields.length -1];
    return section.Value === 'Department';
});


// flatten result:
deps = [];
for(var i = 0; i < departments.length; i++){

    for(var j = 0; j < departments[i].Fields.length; j++){
        deps.push({ key: departments[i].Fields[j].Key, 
                    value: departments[i].Fields[j].Value })
    }


}
console.dir(deps);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwpy35hg/1/

To get departments as 2 arrays:

```
var departments = data.Item.filter(function(item){
    var section = item.Fields[item.Fields.length -1];
    return section.Value === 'Department';
}).map(function(deps){
    return deps.Fields;
});
```

Comment: Hi, your code combines both the departments, it hould come as as array with two departments

Comment: @user804401 You should be able to figure that out based on this code ;) Anyway, I've posted an example